# Get Key in property List using GQL

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gqlquery

I am developing a Python app using Google App Engine. I want to retrieve property list from an entity along with the key. I am using the code below

```
recs = db.GqlQuery('select __key__,content from FileHistory')
```

but I am not able to get the key attribute. Does anybody know how to do it. Do I need to use any keyword to retrieve it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant to use [projection query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Query_Projection) then you don't need to pass the request for **key**, it will returned with every query implicitly.

```
recs = db.GqlQuery('select content from FileHistory')
for rec in recs:
  print rec.key(), rec.content
```